# Какая связь между исходными файлами(.cs) и исполняемыми(.dll, .exe) после компиляции проекта? С#

Tags: c#, компиляция

Какая связь между исходными файлами(.cs) и исполняемыми(.dll, .exe) после компиляции проекта в С#? Если например у меня в каждом исходном файле находится класс, в котором есть массив из 2 элементов, первый из которых является меткой, а второй идентификационный номер исходного файла. Метка нужна для нахождения идентификационного номера файла. Тогда после компиляции проекта, прочитав исполняемые файлы в бинарном режиме, можно найти эти метки, а затем идентификационный номер. А что если мы просмотрев все исполняемые файлы не находим все идентификационные номера исходных файлов? Это означает, что эти файлы не нужны для сборки проекта?

Comment: А какая ваша цель? Чего вы пытаетесь добиться с точки зрения программной логики? Есть законные с точки зрения .NET методы получения имени текущего файла с исходным текстом. А вы пытаетесь полагаться на предположения о том, как именно ведёт себя компилятор.

Comment: @VladD хочу выявить избыточные исходные файлы, чтобы удалить их и попробовать запустить проект без них.

Comment: Классы, определённые в файле, могут вполне вызываться через рефлексию. Поэтому даже если проект компилируется и запускается без какого-то файла, не факт, что он не грохнется с исключением рано или поздно.